# Hide/show functions only work one at a time? - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two jquery functions like this:

```
$(document).ready(init); 
  function init() { 
  $(".alphaleft").hover(function (g) { 
  $(".boxy,.yee").show(); 
  }, 
  function (g) { 
  $(".boxy,.yee").hide(); 
  }); 
}

$(document).ready(init); 
  function init() { 
  $(".alpharight").hover(function (h) { 
  $(".tea,.coffee").show(); 
  }, 
  function (h) { 
  $(".tea,.coffee").hide(); 
  }); 
}
```

But only one shows up at a time? Like if I comment one of them the other one works fine, and vise versa... Not sure what is causing this. Any suggestions? Been pulling my hair out for an hour now :(

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/W3TTh here is my jfiddle!

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ sample ?

Comment: the second `init` function overwrites the first before either is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the functions to `ready` as anonymous functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".alphaleft").hover(function (g) { 
    $(".boxy,.yee").show(); 
   }, 
   function (g) { 
    $(".boxy,.yee").hide(); 
   }); 
});

$(document).ready(function () { 
  $(".alpharight").hover(function (h) { 
    $(".tea,.coffee").show(); 
  }, 
  function (h) { 
    $(".tea,.coffee").hide(); 
  }); 
});
```

This prevents the conflict that is occurring because the functions are named the same.  Since you declare the functions outside of a closure, the second function will override the first due to the shared name between the two and their global scope.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfzjH/) demonstrates how the `init` method is overridden.  It can also be demonstrated by rearranging your code:

```
//Init function created  
function init() { 
  $(".alphaleft").hover(function (g) { 
  $(".boxy,.yee").show(); 
  }, 
  function (g) { 
  $(".boxy,.yee").hide(); 
  }); 
}

//Init function overridden
function init() { 
  $(".alpharight").hover(function (h) { 
  $(".tea,.coffee").show(); 
  }, 
  function (h) { 
  $(".tea,.coffee").hide(); 
  }); 
}

//Init function called 2x after being overridden
$(document).ready(init);
$(document).ready(init);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for two `ready` functions. There is also no need for calling a separate `init` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".alphaleft").hover(function () { 
      $(".boxy,.yee").show(); 
  }, function () { 
      $(".boxy,.yee").hide(); 
  }); 

  $(".alpharight").hover(function () { 
      $(".tea,.coffee").show(); 
  }, function ) { 
      $(".tea,.coffee").hide(); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're redeclaring the `init` function.
Just wrap it in only one function like this:

```
$(document).ready(init); 
function init() { 
    $(".alphaleft").hover(function (g) { 
        $(".boxy,.yee").show(); 
    }, 
    function (g) { 
        $(".boxy,.yee").hide(); 
    }); 
    $(".alpharight").hover(function (h) { 
        $(".tea,.coffee").show(); 
    }, 
    function (h) { 
        $(".tea,.coffee").hide(); 
    });    
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DrYZV/